# Can a virtual mikrotik box bridge a hyper-v internal network with a hyper-v external network?

Tags: hyper-v, bridge, mikrotik, networking

I am trying to set up a Mikrotik router as a transparent firewall on my network.  I got the machine working on a hardware MT box, but my boss wants the MT virtualized.  I have been trying the set up where my virtual windows box talks to the Mikrotik via private or internal network on the Hyper-V host.  I can get the two machines to talk, but as soon as I set up a bridge on the MT, all traffic ceases between the two.  Is it possible to create a bridge for this purpose (having the MT silently in front of my firewalled server)?

I could really use some help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as long as the NIC support is "there" with Mikrotik when virtualized.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. Mikrotik can run as bridge or router between different NIC's - if you run CHR (the virtual mikrotik you should use) on a VM and have multiple virtual NIC that point to the external and internal network - you got yourself a high speed connection. WAY higher speed than you can do at the moment with Mikrotik hardware, outside of pure bridging (switches now can handle 40g on mikrotik - that is hard to beat - but as router.... use that myself).